# Set default year toa DatePicker without calling the SelectedDate_Changed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am coding **WPF/C#** application with Visual Studio 2010. Not sure which API I am using since I am noob WPF programmer.

I need to develop a desktop application and I need to set a default year for my **DatePicker** components. Even if I set in the xaml code, something like  **SelectedDate="01/01/2035"**, it calls the **SelectedDate_Changed** event of the specific DatePicker and the compilation breaks with NullPointer exception since not all the visual components have been initialized(ContentRendered still not done).

How can I initialize a DatePicker to a year of my choosing without it calling events?

Comment: I recommend using the MVVM pattern and avoiding using event-handlers directly.

Comment: @Dai you might understand this stuff much more than me. Sadly there is not time for overhauling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XAML**:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="01/01/2035" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" />
```

**Code behind**:

```
private bool _initialized = false;
public MainWindow1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _initialized = true;
}
private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_initialized)
        return;
    //....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I though of similar thing. I had a Boolean variable called firstVisit which is true and set to false after the content is rendered.